# Azure Java SDK 1.0.0 osDiskStorageAccountType() returns null always

Tags: java, azure, azure-java-sdk

I started using Azure Java SDK 1.0.0 recently and I noticed that for a VM the method `osDiskStorageAccountType()` always returns null. The SDK is unable to even get information about the attached data disks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.compute.fluent.ivirtualmachine.osdiskstorageaccounttype?view=azuremgmtcompute-fluent-1.0.0) we know that osDiskStorageAccountType is only available for managed disk (this is c# based API but I think it will suitable for Java). Here is a snippet:

> Gets the storage account type of the managed disk backing Os disk.

If you create Azure VM based on managed disk, it will give you related info.

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eqj]

Comment: I was expecting the information to be available for unmanaged disk as well since they belong either to Standard or Premium Storage. Thanks for the response.